# Returning Assembly Version Numbers from a different application

Tags: vb.net, api, methods, .net-assembly

Let me preface this question by saying I am fairly new to the concept of Assemblies.  I am trying to create a method with in a namespace I have called API. The methods look like this:

```
Partial Public Class AppInfo

    ' This function will return the VersionMajor Element of the Assembly Version
    Function VersionMajor() As String
        Dim txt As String = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetName.Version.Major.ToString()
        If txt.Length > 0 Then
            Return txt
        Else
            Return String.Empty
        End If
    End Function

    ' This function will return the VersionMinor Element of the Assembly Version
    Function VersionMinor() As String
        Dim txt As String = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetName.Version.Minor.ToString()
        If txt.Length > 0 Then
            Return txt
        Else
            Return String.Empty
        End If
    End Function

    ' This function will return the VersionPatch Element of the Assembly Version
    Function VersionPatch() As String
        Dim txt As String = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.Build.ToString()
        If txt.Length > 0 Then
            Return txt
        Else
            Return String.Empty
        End If
    End Function

    ' This function will return the entire Version Number of the Assembly Version
    Function Version() As String
        Dim Func As New AppInfo
        Dim txt As String = VersionMajor() + "." + VersionMinor() + "." + VersionPatch()
        If txt.Length > 0 Then
            Return txt
        Else
            Return String.Empty
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

I have other projects within the same solution that call the API as an additional reference.  What I'd like to accomplish is say I have a project that references the API project called Test.  In the home controller of test I have a view data that calls the Version method. Like this:

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
  Dim func As New API.AppInfo
  ViewData("1") = func.Version
  Return View()
End Function
```

I'd like the viewdata to return the Version number of the Test assembly, but instead this returns the API Assembly version. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MSDN, [`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Gets the assembly that contains the code that is currently executing.

and it is always API assembly, because it is place when `AppInfo.Version` is defined and executed.

What you want is to get information about calling assembly, meaning assembly that called your function `AppInfo.Version`. You can get it by similar method [`Assembly.GetCallingAssembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Returns the Assembly of the method that invoked the currently executing method.

**Note:** In your code `Version` is calling `VersionPatch` etc. internally which results in internal assembly call. It would be better that `Version` use `GetCallingAssembly` directly.

**Note 2:** Read carefully about method inlinig in the `GetCallingAssembly` documentation provided above and decorate your `Version` method with `MethodImplOptions.NoInlining` attribute to avoid inlining.